# I am having issue in changing package name of multi module project in Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on a multi-module project app, I want to change its package name, I tried the normal method of changing the package name that is, changing the name by compacting the middle package of java, then changing in the manifest, and then changing in build.gradle, but the issue in this project is there are multiple modules, so when I am performing the above steps, they are throwing many errors and when I try to change all old package names from everywhere by replacing old package name by shortcut ctrl+shift+R, then also it's throwing many errors, so please give me steps to change the package name of the multi-module project.

Github Project Link-- https://github.com/vector-im/element-android

[image]